# Autofilter VBA help "error 1004"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to filter a column name "Sales Level 1" and it contains lots of sales levels out of which I only need "Americas, Global Service Provider, WW Distribution" the sheet has columns from A to Y and total of 43295 records.

here is my code which is throwing error 1004 " AutoFilter method of range class failed"

```
Dim objXLApp As Object    
Dim xlApp As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Activesheet.Range("$A1:$Y43295").AutoFilter Field:=16,_    
Criteria1:=Array("Americas", "GLOBAL SERVICE PROVIDER", "WW Distribution"),_
       Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I have other codes in this function and this is one of them.

Comment: Is this the only code that has run by the time the autofilter method is called? If I am not mistaken, you need to set the range as being able to be autofiltered before changing the criteria. I could be mistaken as I don't use autofilter often, but this is where I would check first. Also, you are creating an excel application but you aren't creating a file? Do you simply want to just open a sheet and filter that? You can use FollowHyperlink or Workbooks.Open for that purpose.

Comment: Your line continuations are illegal. The line continuation token is defined by a whitespace followed by an underscore - the code you posted wouldn't even compile. Also the first executable instruction `Set xlApp = ...` stands on its own, line-continuing it would confuse the heck out of VBA... and wouldn't compile either.

Comment: Hey thank you for the response! I made an error while posting my code. my actual code is xlApp.Activesheet.Range("$A1:$Y43295").AutoFilter Field:=16,_    
Criteria1:=Array("Americas", "GLOBAL SERVICE PROVIDER", "WW Distribution"),_
       Operator:=xlFilterValues

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because with "CreateObject" you start a new excel instance so that the ActiveSheet will be an empty one

While if you want to catch a running Excel instance which already has the proper sheet as the "active" one

```
Dim objXLApp As Object    
Dim xlApp As Object

Set xlApp = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")

xlApp.Activesheet.Range("$A1:$Y43295").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Array("Americas", "GLOBAL SERVICE PROVIDER", "WW Distribution"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Thank you ! however I made a mistake in my post. I have my code exactly like the one you posted and it is throwing that error. I didnt mean to put "_" after the set statement

Comment: @MilanBillimoria your post is calling `CreateObject` (creates a new instance). This answer is calling `GetObject` (uses an existing instance). If your *actual code* is using `GetObject`, then you should edit your question to say so. People can't guess what your *actual code* looks like, and keep in mind that "chameleon questions" that change every time there's a new answer, are terribly irritating for everyone involved. Please, *take your time* when asking a question on SO.

Comment: @MilanBillimoria, did you get through it?